# Como acessar um campo (valor) de um JSON

Tags: android, android-studio

estou com um problema, eu tenho este JSON `{"cidade":{"nome":"Mag�","uf":"RJ","atualizacao":"2019-07-27","previsao":[{"dia":"2019-07-27","tempo":"pn","maxima":29,"minima":17,"iuv":6},{"dia":"2019-07-28","tempo":"vn","maxima":26,"minima":19,"iuv":6},{"dia":"2019-07-29","tempo":"vn","maxima":26,"minima":16,"iuv":6},{"dia":"2019-07-30","tempo":"pn","maxima":28,"minima":17,"iuv":6}]}}`
, eu preciso apenas pegar o primeiro dado da chave "maxima" e o que eu vejo na internet são soluções usando serialização, eu não desejo salvar todos esses dados. Uma outra dúvida, esse JSON está correto em questão de formatação ? Como eu faço pra acessar ele no Android Studio ?

Comment: para validar json eu costumo usar esse site https://jsonlint.com/. No seu json tem um erro do tem uma } a mais, a penúltima está sobrando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu caso é um array dentro de outro array voce tem que ir "navegando" e pegando os nodos;

Eu coloco dentro de um AsyncTask e no metodo onPostExecute faço o tratamento de leitura.

Eu faço assim para ler valores

```
JSONObject obj = null;
JSONArray jsonArray = null;

try {
  obj = new JSONObject(jsonResposta);

  jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj.get("ev_resposta");

} catch (JSONException e) {
  log("JSONException "+e.getMessage()+"\n"+this.getClass().getName().toString()+"\n onPostExecute");
}
```

Você também pode fazer obj.get(1); para ler, colocando dentro de um for e fazendo a leitura registro a registro.